# How to query the same table multiple times?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 table, Application, School, Student

Table **School** :

| id | name | school_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | sch_1 | 001 |
| 1 | sch_2 | 002 |
| 2 | sch_3 | 003 |
| 3 | sch_4 | 004 |
| 4 | sch_5 | 005 |
| 5 | sch_6 | 006 |
| 6 | sch_7 | 007 |
| 7 | sch_8 | 008 |
| 8 | sch_9 | 009 |
| 9 | sch_10 | 010 |
| 10 | sch_11 | 011 |

Table **Application** ：

| app_id | sch_choice_1 | sch_choice_2 | sch_choice_3 | sch_choice_4 | sch_choice_5 | sch_choice_6 | sch_choice_7 | sch_choice_8 | sch_choice_9 | sch_choice_10 | student |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 1 |
| 2 | 9 | 8 | 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 9 | 0 | 8 | 7 | 2 | 6 | 3 | 5 | 4 | 3 |

Table **Student** ：

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | student1 |
| 2 | student2 |
| 3 | student3 |

I want to select the school choices for each student with the school detail.

My ideal output is like below

| app_id | student | name1 | school_code1 | name2 | school_code2 | name3 | school_code3 | name4 | school_code4 | name5 | school_code5 | name6 | school_code6 | name7 | school_code7 | name8 | school_code8 | name9 | school_code9 | name10 | school_code10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | sch_1 | 001 | sch_2 | 002 | sch_3 | 003 | sch_4 | 004 | sch_5 | 005 | sch_6 | 006 | sch_7 | 007 | sch_8 | 008 | sch_9 | 009 | sch_10 | 010 |
| 2 | 2 | sch_10 | 010 | sch_9 | 009 | sch_8 | 008 | sch_7 | 007 | sch_6 | 006 | sch_5 | 005 | sch_4 | 004 | sch_3 | 003 | sch_2 | 002 | sch_1 | 001 |

I have tried using left join , but in order to get all the 10 choices school details I will have to left join the School table 10 times. Is there any better ways to get the same output?

SQL that currently using is like below :

```
select 
app.app_id,
app.student,
r1.NAME as name1,
r1.SCHOOL_CODE as school_code1,
r2.NAME as name2,
r2.SCHOOL_CODE as school_code2,
r3.NAME as name3,
r3.SCHOOL_CODE as school_code3,
r4.NAME as name4,
r4.SCHOOL_CODE as school_code4,
r5.NAME as name5,
r5.SCHOOL_CODE as school_code5,
r6.NAME as name6,
r6.SCHOOL_CODE as school_code6,
r7.NAME as name7,
r7.SCHOOL_CODE as school_code7,
r8.NAME as name8,
r8.SCHOOL_CODE as school_code8,
r9.NAME as name9,
r9.SCHOOL_CODE as school_code9,
r10.NAME as name10,
r10.SCHOOL_CODE as school_code10
from 
  T_APPLICATION app 
  left join T_SCHOOL r1 on r1.ID = app.SCH_CHOICE1 
  left join T_SCHOOL r2 on r2.ID = app.SCH_CHOICE2 
  left join T_SCHOOL r3 on r3.ID = app.SCH_CHOICE3 
  left join T_SCHOOL r4 on r4.ID = app.SCH_CHOICE4 
  left join T_SCHOOL r5 on r5.ID = app.SCH_CHOICE5 
  left join T_SCHOOL r6 on r6.ID = app.SCH_CHOICE6 
  left join T_SCHOOL r7 on r7.ID = app.SCH_CHOICE7 
  left join T_SCHOOL r8 on r8.ID = app.SCH_CHOICE8 
  left join T_SCHOOL r9 on r9.ID = app.SCH_CHOICE8 
  left join T_SCHOOL r10 on r10.ID = app.SCH_CHOICE10
```

Comment: Perhaps post your sql too.

Comment: @AllenKing added the sql in the post

Comment: You can store Application (app_id, student_id,school_id). Each choice is 1 row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use subquery instead of join

```sql
select 
   app_id,
   student,
   (select name from T_SCHOOL where id=sch_choice_1) as name1,
   (select school_code from T_SCHOOL where id=sch_choice_1) as school_code1,
   (select name from T_SCHOOL where id=sch_choice_2) as name2,
   (select school_code from T_SCHOOL where id=sch_choice_2) as school_code2,
   
   ......

   (select name from T_SCHOOL where id=sch_choice_10) as name10,
   (select school_code from T_SCHOOL where id=sch_choice_10) as school_code10,  
from T_APPLICATION
```

However, it would be better to store each choice in one row and modify the T_APPLICATION table to (app_id, student_id, school_id, order)